# What is the proper speed of writing iptables rules?

Tags: kubernetes

We have run 100 services in our kubernetes cluster, so the number of iptables rules grown to 900+(our services are `node-port` type). Then we found that the speed of creating `kube-proxy` has been slown down.

After analyzing the log, we found the speed of writing `iptables` rules is really low----it took about 50ms to write one rule, so it took about 40s to flush all `iptables` rules.

So I was wondering about what is the proper speed of writing `iptables` rules? Is my case reasonable or not?

Comment: If you're running 1 iptables commands for every rule, http://www.iptables.info/en/iptables-save-restore-rules.html probably explains why it's not that fast (each iptables command dumps the existing rules, adds the new one, and re-loads the new set of rules)

Comment: What about using ipset instead of iptables if you have so many rules? See http://ipset.netfilter.org/ It usually gives you much better network throughput.

Comment: @nos If I did not misunderstand, what you mean is that if I was running 1 iptables commands for every rule, then the speed of 50ms is reasonable?

Comment: @JiriS Er..The command used in `kube-proxy` is written in code, so it can not be modified by myself.

Comment: @SunGengze Yes, 50ms wouldn't be out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue.  The newer kube-proxy uses iptables-save and iptables-restore to do this, which is constant-time rather than linear.  We're looking at backporting that logic to the "userspace" kube-proxy version, but it probably won't make it for v1.2 release.

TL;DR: newer kube-proxy makes this a non-issue.